# Apache Ignite H2 Debug Console doesn't start

Tags: java, h2, ignite

OS: Ubuntu 18.04 
Apache Ignite: 2.9.0 
Browser: Firefox 81.0.2

I followed the documentation at:
https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/sql-performance-and-debugging#using-h2-debug-console

and ran `export JVM_OPTS="-DIGNITE_H2_DEBUG_CONSOLE=true"` in my terminal.

Then I ran `./ignite.sh` but it did not start the console at all.

I then tried to set the environment variable: `export IGNITE_H2_DEBUG_CONSOLE=true`
but again to no avail.

Logs:
https://pastebin.com/zP450eMP

Highlights:

```
[18:12:12,249][INFO][main][IgniteKernal] IGNITE_HOME=/home/me/Programs/apache-ignite-2.9.0-bin
[18:12:12,249][INFO][main][IgniteKernal] VM arguments: [-XX:+AggressiveOpts, -DIGNITE_H2_DEBUG_CONSOLE=true, -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8, -DIGNITE_QUIET=true, -DIGNITE_SUCCESS_FILE=/home/me/Programs/apache-ignite-2.9.0-bin/work/ignite_success_8a7ec5b2-6e10-4824-a98e-f3ae20e6291d, -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote, -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=49122, -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false, -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false, -DIGNITE_HOME=/home/me/Programs/apache-ignite-2.9.0-bin, -DIGNITE_PROG_NAME=./ignite.sh]
...
[18:12:13,150][WARNING][main][IgniteH2Indexing] Serialization of Java objects in H2 was enabled.
...
[18:12:14,809][INFO][disco-notifier-worker-#41][IgniteH2Indexing] SQL parameter 'sql.disabledFunctions' was changed from 'null' to '[FILE_WRITE, CANCEL_SESSION, MEMORY_USED, CSVREAD, LINK_SCHEMA, MEMORY_FREE, FILE_READ, CSVWRITE, SESSION_ID, LOCK_MODE]'
```

As you can see, `DIGNITE_H2_DEBUG_CONSOLE` was correctly received as a JVM option with the value of `true`.

The logs only had the above two lines which dealt with H2. No other error or warning was present with regards to the H2 console or H2 itself.

How do I start H2 console and why is it not starting automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please do not use H2 console, it is irrelevant for many releases of Apache Ignite and in fact broken in some releases. Unfortunately it still appears in the docs.

It was removed in Apache Ignite 2.8: [IGNITE-11333](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IGNITE-11333)

I will try to edit doc.

You can use some external tooling such as DBeaver or built-in sqlline.

Comment: Ok thank you for letting me know. It would be best if the docs were updated (maybe with a warning) as you said.

Comment: Oh okay. I was using 2.8.1 until a few days ago so I tried it on that and when it failed, I tried it on v2.9.0.